# Fetching images from Youtube - unpredictable 403

Tags: youtube-api, http-status-code-403

I'm successfully fetching channels from the Youtube Data API.

Later, when I use the image urls (of the channel profile images) in my React components, using a prop named image:

```
image={{src: source.content.image}}
```

I'm only getting some of the images:

[image: Only some images are displayed]

The ones that don't show give me:
[image]

I'm currently using the .medium option

```
image: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium?.url.toString() || ""
```

when I fetch them initially.
.default brings the same issue.

On some days I only get a few 403s when displayling those images. On others almost every image url results in a 403.
I'm also under the impression, that some particular images have a higher chance of being shown. Such as the two images above for the search term "ok".
Here are their urls:
https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLTJe9ob0HBWUlnST_EbCGMUq9buu36epv8KO-HVBw=s240-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj
https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLTPFApx-CKviVzQzWT2HCNAMDMr3KGOkmOMM3eRVA=s240-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj

Comment: what are the values of the images that are not shown? - [edit] and add them in your question. Also, it helps you provide more source code - in order to see if in other parts of your code are the cause(s) of these results.

Comment: the images that aren't shown aren't there, because their src urls return 403s